# Stub program added to existing bin

Tags: esp32

I have a bin file which works when run on an older ESP32 board. The New board has a different Power Chip the APX2102 the old board has the APX192. So what I would like to know is, if it is possible to load a bin which initialises the APX2102 and then that calls the original bin.